# Dynamically add child view items in expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my android app, i need to dynamically add child view based on button click. i don't know how to do that. i share the sample image. if any one knows please help me
[image]

Comment: my question and the above link both r different

Comment: simply create your views in xml, then onclick button setvisibility or gone

Comment: Your question is so vague that we can assume it is a duplicate. If it is not : provide more details on what/why it is different and the duplicate will be removed.

Comment: engar Waseem Arain, the child view may be  10 or 1000 based on user. so it is not possible in xml layout

Comment: @user1517638 10 or 1000 based on user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer for my question. for every button click just inflate the xml desiged layout. so the layout can be added one by one. the codes are here

```
LayoutInflater IInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    String[] names = { "Joe", "Jane", "Herkimer" };
    while (run >= 1) {

        View storeitems = IInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_child_item,
                null);
        productCode = (TextView) storeitems.findViewById(R.id.productCode);
        productName = (TextView) storeitems.findViewById(R.id.productName);
        noOfQuantity = (TextView) storeitems
                .findViewById(R.id.noOfQuantity);
        int i = run - 1;
        productCode.setText(names[i]);
        linearLayout.addView(storeitems, 0);
        run--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement OnChildClickListener in your Activity and implemet this method..

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

           //Add new chid data in your list (ex ArrayLis or Array whatever you use)
          adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() // BaseExpandableListAdapter's adapter...


    return true;
}
```

Is it work work for you?